# Nesterov Acceleration in Proximal Iteration with Strictly Positive Variable?

Tags: constraint, convex-optimization

I have a cost function of the form $f(x) - \log(x)$, where $f$ is some smooth function mapping $\mathbb{R}^n_+\to\mathbb{R}$and $x$ is restricted to be nonnegative by the problem constraints (and for course the logarithm term means it has to be strictly positive). I'm currently minimizing this function using Proximal gradient descent, treating $-\log(x)$ as the nonsmooth term with known proximal operator.

I wanted to try Nesterov acceleration to see if it could help out. Just to develop notation, I'll write down the basic iteration I'm using, which is modeled on the FISTA method (which has an unrestricted variable and uses the prox associated with the aboslute value function instead):

$$
y^t = \textrm{prox}^{-\log}_{\eta}(x^{t-1}-\eta\nabla f(x^{t-1})) \\
x^t = (1-\gamma^t)y^t + \gamma y^{t-1}
$$

where $\eta$ is a step size and $\gamma^t$ is the Nesterov combination coefficient computed in the usual manner.

Since $y^t$ is coming out of a proximal operator which "knows" about the $\log$ term, it is always strictly positive. However, I've found that the variable $x^t$ can be negative despite this (if $y^{t-1}$ is much smaller than $y^t$). It is not possible to subsequently compute $\nabla f(x^t)$, since $x^t$ is outside of the domain of $f$.

Are there modified procedures that can allow Nesterov acceleration to work in my case?